# Component painted to image renders with ugly fonts

Tags: java, windows, swing, fonts

When I'm rendering a Swing component to an image the fonts are different then when the component is rendered on screen. Here is an image showing the difference:

[image]

And this is the code:

```
public static BufferedImage renderComponent(Component component) {
    int width = component.getWidth();
    int height = component.getHeight();
    BufferedImage buffImage = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
    Graphics2D g = (Graphics2D) buffImage.getGraphics();
    g.setFont(component.getFont());
    g.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
    g.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_TEXT_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_TEXT_ANTIALIAS_ON);
    component.paint(g);
    g.dispose();
    return buffImage;
}
```

What should I change to make a perfect screen shot of a Swing component? (The app is running on Windows 7)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After comparing the ScreenImage class (suggested by **camickr**) I found the cause of the problem. If I create a BufferedImage with the type set to TYPE_INT_RGB instead of TYPE_INT_ARGB the fonts are fine.

Comment: Had exactly the same problem. With `TYPE_INT_ARGB`, the fonts are ugly, and when used within an animation that started with the on-screen image (having the good fonts), it is perceived as if all text was pixelshifted. It is indeed solved with `TYPE_INT_RGB`. (I'm using on-screen and on-image in an animation sequence that blurs the panel content, so I let the panel draw to a buffer first, and then start blurring the buffer in an animation).

Answer (score 1):

> What should I change to make a perfect screen shot of a Swing component?

I would guess you should not be providing rendering hints.

I use the [Screen Image](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/13/screen-image/) class for this (it is basically your code with a few other features built in).

Answer (score 0):

Class Robot

```
public synchronized BufferedImage createScreenCapture(Rectangle screenRect)
```

?

Comment: Unfortunately that won't work as I need to capture an image even if the component isn't visible on the screen.